# How to replace php replace \ by \\ within PHP?

Tags: php, string, escaping

anybody know how can I  replace `\` by `\\` ?

input string : `Télephone dsadad;'''´ ''''aa\`

```
 php> $in =  "Télephone dsadad;'''´ ''''aa\";
 ... echo str_replace("\\","\\\\",$in);
Multiline input has no syntactic completion:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in Command line code on line 2
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_replace:

```
str_replace('/', '//', 'abc/def/xyz');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
abc//def//xyz
```

Comment: I think I reversed slash in my answer here, please use `str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $str);` for backslash replacement.

Comment: $st = "Télephone dsadad;'''´ ''''aa\"; ?

Comment: Your input string has wrong syntax. It should be **`"Télephone dsadad;'''´ ''''aa\\"`** instead of `"Télephone dsadad;'''´ ''''aa\"`

Answer (score 3):

Um... Same as any other string?

```
$out = str_replace("\\","\\\\",$in);
```

The only difference is that you have to escape each `\` in the string.

Comment: Why use double quotes when you don't need to?  Using single quotes is more efficient than double quotes as the contents of them is not evaluated, which also means you don't need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Have you tried running `str_replace('\','\\',$in)`? Didn't think so.

Comment: Oops- I forgot you still have to escape.  However, double quotes are STILL unnecessary.

Comment: $st = "Télephone dsadad;'''´ ''''aa\"; ?

Comment: Looking at your code, I think the answer is... just type another backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do string replaces:

```
preg_replace("\\", "\\\\", $string);
```

Notice that the `\` is a special character and has to be escaped!

However, if you're interested in escaping strings, PHP has some built-in functions to do that:

See the [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function:

```
addslashes($string);
```